# C# calculate combinations of words from an arbitrary number of columns

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation

There are a lot of combo solutions for single arrays or vectors of arrays where you need every possible permutation, but I need slightly different solution. Ive tried hacking pieces together but can no longer see the wood for the trees.

I need a solution that will take a csv file which contains anything up to 50 columns and any number of rows of words per column. The number of rows per column can be different.

what i need to do is take this input and in turn iterate through each column choosing one word to create every possible row combination, skipping any row/column that is null. nested loops would do this for a preset number of columns but as columns change this is a problem. fairly new to programming. hoping its a fairly simple logical concept im missing.

For example:

input:
bear, claw, donut
chicken, salad,
tuna,,salad

output:
bear, claw, donut
bear, salad, donut
bear, salad
chicken, claw, donut
chicken, salad, donut
chicken, claw
chicken, salad
chicken, salad, donut
...
tuna, claw, salad
tuna, salad
etc

Comment: This is a really interesting problem... working on it!

Comment: Interesting is an interesting way of saying frustrating

Comment: Haha, it's more interesting than frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing an answer at the same time as [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37186067/2700399), but shortly after, the requirements became unclear, so I refrained from posting it. Now that they are clear, here is an alternative that uses [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)s. It also does not need to `Array.Reverse()` every answer.

## Original answer text

You will want to solve this problem recursively.

The code below assumes that you've already parsed the CSV to some `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s.

```
static void Main()
{
    var wordLists = new List<string[]>()
    {
        new string[] { "bear", "chicken", "tuna" },
        new string[] { "claw", null, "salad" },
        null,
        new string[] { "donut", "salad", null },
    };

    foreach (var result in AllPermutations(wordLists)) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
    }
}

// our recursive function. 
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> AllPermutations(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> wordLists, int index = 0, List<string> current = null)
{
    if (current == null) 
    {
        current = new List<string>();
    }
    
    if (index == wordLists.Count()) 
    { // the end condtion. it is reached when we are past the last list
        yield return current;
    }
    else
    { // if we are not at the end yet, loop through the entire list
      // of words, appending each one, then recursively combining
      // the other lists, and finally removing the word again.
        var wordList = wordLists.ElementAt(index);
        if (wordList != null)
        {
            foreach (var word in wordList)
            {
                if (word == null) continue;
                current.Add(word);
                foreach (var result in AllPermutations(wordLists, index + 1, current)) 
                {
                    yield return result;
                }
                current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var result in AllPermutations(wordLists, index + 1, current)) 
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with 50 columns, there could be a **lot** of combinations **really fast**.

Comment: I think ill make a spreadsheet that grabs the largest and smallest words from each row, then at least its only 2 rows at most. 

ienumerable means nothing to me. I can do basic scripting but this ... - im not a developer but somehow its landed on my desk. Can you point me to an article that shows how to read a csv into an ienumerable?

Comment: @Dan `IEnumerable` is something you can enumerate (for example by using `foreach`). It is implemented by many collections, including arrays and `List`s. The power in using it over `string[]` or `List<string>` is that you can pass either (or something else that implements it), and the function will work correctly. As for parsing a CSV-file, I would suggest using _method 2_ from [this article](http://danashurst.com/parsing-a-csv-file/). Finally, if you're not a developer, I don't think that this belongs on your desk.

Comment: Preach. I already have something reading the csv into a list<array> but can you just pass that list into the parameter of your function?

Comment: Both `List` and arrays implement `IEnumerable`, so you should be able to. My example is also passing a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got right what you're asking. You seem to be missing some of the solutions.

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> GetAllCombinations(string[,] input, Stack<string> current = null, int currentCol = 0)
{
    if (current == null) current = new Stack<string>();

    var rows = input.GetLength(0);
    var cols = input.GetLength(1);

    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        if (input[row, currentCol] == null) continue;

        current.Push(input[row, currentCol]);
        if (currentCol == cols - 1)
        {
            var result = current.ToArray();
            Array.Reverse(result);
            yield return result;
        }
        else
        {
            var subResults = GetAllCombinations(input, current, currentCol + 1);
            foreach (var subResult in subResults)
                yield return subResult;
        }
        current.Pop();
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var input = new[,]
    {
        {"bear", "claw", "donut"},
        {"chicken", "salad", null},
        {"tuna", null, "salad"}
    };

    foreach (var comb in GetAllCombinations(input))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", comb));
}
```

and the output:

```
bear,claw,donut
bear,claw,salad
bear,salad,donut
bear,salad,salad
chicken,claw,donut
chicken,claw,salad
chicken,salad,donut
chicken,salad,salad
tuna,claw,donut
tuna,claw,salad
tuna,salad,donut
tuna,salad,salad
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comments - i hit enter for a new line and didnt realise it submitted the comment #noob. This code seems to be a little piece of art!

Comment: Though an issue with this is when the csv is imported you cant predefine the array size, and because each column size is different ...

a way around this is to use a list<array> ?